# Why wildcards calling is not workin?

Tags: python, wildcard, bioinformatics, snakemake

I'm writing this code to use snakemake to operate bioinformatic pipelines, but for some reason the variable "wildcards.sra" is not being defined in the get_fastq and get_fastp functions. What am I not doing right?

This is the config.yaml:

```
#Number of threads (integer)
threads : 40

#Memory ram usage (integer):
ram : "60"

#NCBI's SRA accesions list:
SRA_acessions :
  - "SRR6308266"
  - "SRR1525658"
  - "SRR6308195"
  - "SRR6206507"
  - "SRR22957809"
  - "SRR22957815"
  - "SRR21169022"
  - "SRR13066396"
  - "SRR7904254"
  - "SRR6308265"
  - "SRR1525659"
  - "SRR1525660"

#Path to the directory + name of the directory (e.g. /home/user/results)

directory_path : "/home/apis/Icaro3"
```

This is the Snakefile:

```
configfile : "workflow/config/config.yaml"

SRA_ARCHIVE = expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}.sra", sra=config['SRA_acessions'], path = config['directory_path'])

include: "rules/common.smk"
include: "rules/sra_toolkit.smk" 
include: "rules/trimming.smk"

#target rules

rule all: #here, we only going to add only rules whose output is not the input of another rule 
   input:
        SRA_ARCHIVE,
        get_fastq,
        get_fastp
```

This is the common.smk, where wildcards.sra is not being recognized:

```
import subprocess

def isPairedSRA(filename):
    # Run fastq-dump to get the metadata
    fastq_dump = ["fastq-dump", "-X", "1", "-Z", "--split-spot", filename]
    command = " ".join(fastq_dump)
    print(f"The command used was: {command}")

    # Capture the output of fastq-dump
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(fastq_dump, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, check=True)
        contents = result.stdout
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        raise Exception(f"Error running fastq-dump on {filename}: {e.stderr}")

    # Count the number of lines in the output
    num_lines = contents.count("\n")

    if num_lines == 4:
        return False
    elif num_lines == 8:
        return True
    else:
        raise Exception("Unexpected output from fastq-dump on", filename)

def get_fastq(wildcards):
    if isPairedSRA(wildcards.sra):
        return expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_{type}.fastq", sra=config['SRA_acessions'], path = config['directory_path'], type = ["1", "2"], **wildcards)
    else:
        return expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}.fastq", sra=config['SRA_acessions'], path = config['directory_path'],**wildcards)

def get_fastp(wildcards):
    if isPairedSRA(wildcards.sra):
        return expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_{type}_filtered.fastq", sra=config['SRA_acessions'], path = config['directory_path'], type = ["1", "2"], **wildcards)
    else:
        return expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_filtered.fastq", sra=config['SRA_acessions'], path = config['directory_path'],**wildcards)
```

This is sra_toolkit.smk:

```
rule prefetch:
    output:
        sra_archive = SRA_ARCHIVE
    params:
        path = config['directory_path'],
        sra_acessions = config['SRA_acessions']
    log:
        "{params.path}/prefetch.log"
    conda:
        "envs/environment_sra_toolkit.yml" #Run with --use-conda option in snakemake to create the environment for the first time 
    shell:
        """
        python scripts/run_prefetch.py --directory_path {params.path} --sra_accessions {params.sra_acessions}
        """

rule fasterq_dump:
    input:
        sra_archive = rules.prefetch.output.sra_archive
    params:
        path = config['directory_path'],
        sra_acessions = config['SRA_acessions']
    threads: config['threads'] #if you use a smaler number to run snakemake, threads will be reduced to this number of cores
    conda:
        "envs/environment_sra_toolkit.yml"
    shell:
        """
        python scripts/run_fasterq_dump.py --threads {threads} --directory_path {params.path} --sra_accessions {params.sra_acessions} --sra_files {input.sra_archive}
        """
```

And this is trimming.smk:

```
rule fastp_pe:
    input:
        sra_archive = get_fastq
    output:
        fastq1 = expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_1_filtered.fastq", sra=config['SRA_acessions'], path = config['directory_path']),
        fastq2 = expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_2_filtered.fastq", sra=config['SRA_acessions'], path = config['directory_path'])
    params:
        path = config['directory_path'],
        sra_acessions = config['SRA_acessions']
    threads: config['threads']
    conda:
        "envs/environment_fastp.yml"
    shell:
        """
        python scripts/run_fastp.py --threads {threads} --directory_path {params.path} --sra_accessions {params.sra_acessions}
        """ 

rule fastp_se:
    input:
        sra_archive = get_fastq
    output:
        fastq = expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_filtered.fastq", sra=config['SRA_acessions'], path = config['directory_path'])
    params:
        path = config['directory_path'],
        sra_acessions = config['SRA_acessions']
    threads: config['threads']
    conda:
        "envs/environment_fastp.yml"
    shell:
        """
        python scripts/run_fastp.py --threads {threads} --directory_path {params.path} --sra_accessions {params.sra_acessions}
        """  

rule ribodetector_pe:
    input:
        fastq_filtered = get_fastp
    output:
        fastq_ribodetector1 = expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_ribodetector1.fastq", sra=config['SRA_acessions'], path = config['directory_path']),
        fastq_ribodetector2 = expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_ribodetector2.fastq", sra=config['SRA_acessions'], path = config['directory_path'])
    params:
        path = config['directory_path'],
        sra_acessions = config['SRA_acessions']
    threads: config['threads']
    conda:
        "envs/environment_ribodetector.yml"
    shell:
        """
        python scripts/run_ribodetector.py --threads {threads} --directory_path {params.path} --sra_accessions {params.sra_acessions}
        """ 

rule ribodetector_se:
    input:
        fastq_filtered = get_fastp
    output:
        fastq_ribodetector1 = expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_ribodetector.fastq", sra=config['SRA_acessions'], path = config['directory_path'])
    params:
        path = config['directory_path'],
        sra_acessions = config['SRA_acessions']
    threads: config['threads']
    conda:
        "envs/environment_ribodetector.yml"
    shell:
        """
        python scripts/run_ribodetector.py --threads {threads} --directory_path {params.path} --sra_accessions {params.sra_acessions}
        """
```

In fact, this was the result of a lot of reading and attempts. It was supposed to be working from other examples I've seen.

**EDIT**

I've changed the code to add the expected output files to rule all like this:

Snakefile:

```
import pandas as pd

configfile : "workflow/config/config.yaml"

samples_file = pd.read_table(config['sample_file'], sep='\t')
samples = samples_file["sample"].values.tolist()

include: "rules/common.smk"
include: "rules/sra_toolkit.smk" 
include: "rules/trimming.smk"
include: "rules/mapping.smk"
include: "rules/assembly.smk"

#target rules

rule all:
   input:
      expand("{path}/{sra}/check_{sra}.txt", sra=samples, path = config['directory_path']),
      expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_spades_transcripts.fasta", sra=samples, path = config['directory_path'])
```

common.smk:

```
import subprocess

def is_paired_sra(filename):
    # Run fastq-dump to get the metadata
    fastq_dump = ["conda", "run", "-n", "common", "fastq-dump.3.0.8", "-X", "1", "-Z", "--split-spot", filename]
    command = " ".join(fastq_dump)
    print(f"The command used was: {command}")

    # Capture the output of fastq-dump
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(fastq_dump, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, check=True)
        contents = result.stdout
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        raise Exception(f"Error running fastq-dump on {filename}: {e.stderr}")

    # Count the number of lines in the output
    num_lines = contents.count("\n")

    if num_lines == 5:
        return False
    elif num_lines == 9:
        return True
    else:
        raise Exception("Unexpected output from fastq-dump on", filename)

def get_ribodetector(wildcards):
    if is_paired_sra(wildcards.sra):
        return expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_{{type}}_filtered.fastq".format(
                path=wildcards.path, sra=wildcards.sra), type = ["1", "2"])
    else:
        return "{path}/{sra}/{sra}_filtered.fastq".format(
                path=wildcards.path, sra=wildcards.sra)

def get_mapping(wildcards):
    if is_paired_sra(wildcards.sra):
        return expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_ribodetector_{{type}}.fastq".format(
                path=wildcards.path, sra=wildcards.sra), type = ["1", "2"])
    else:
        return "{path}/{sra}/{sra}_ribodetector.fastq".format(
                path=wildcards.path, sra=wildcards.sra)

def get_assembly(wildcards):
    if is_paired_sra(wildcards.sra):
        return expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_SRA_unaligned.{{type}}.fastq".format(
                path=wildcards.path, sra=wildcards.sra), type = ["1", "2"])
    else:
        return "{path}/{sra}/{sra}_SRA_unaligned.fastq".format(
                path=wildcards.path, sra=wildcards.sra)
```

sra_toolkit.smk:

```
rule download_and_extract_fastq:
    output:
        sra_check = "{path}/{sra}/check_{sra}.txt"
    params:
        threads = config['threads'] 
    conda:
        "../envs/environment_sra_toolkit.yml" #Run with --use-conda option in snakemake to create the environment for the first time 
    shell:
        """
        python workflow/scripts/run_prefetch.py --directory_path {wildcards.path} --sra_accession {wildcards.sra}
        python workflow/scripts/run_fasterq_dump.py --threads {params.threads} --directory_path {wildcards.path} --sra_accession {wildcards.sra}
        touch({output.sra_check})
        """
```

trimming.smk:

```
rule fastp_pe:
    input:
        fastq = get_fastp
    output:
        fastq1 = temp(local("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_1_filtered.fastq")),
        fastq2 = temp(local("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_2_filtered.fastq")),
        json = temp(local("{path}/{sra}/fastp.json")),
        html = temp(local("{path}/{sra}/fastp.html")),
        adapter_sequences = temp(local("{path}/{sra}/adapter_sequences.fasta"))
    params:
        threads = config['threads']
    conda:
        "../envs/environment_fastp.yml"
    shell:
        """
        python workflow/scripts/run_fastp.py --threads {params.threads} --directory_path {wildcards.path} --sra_accession {wuldcards.sra}
        """ 

rule fastp_se:
    input:
        fastq = get_fastp
    output:
        fastq = temp(local("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_filtered.fastq")),
        json = temp(local("{path}/{sra}/fastp.json")),
        html = temp(local("{path}/{sra}/fastp.html")),
        adapter_sequences = temp(local("{path}/{sra}/adapter_sequences.fasta"))
    params:
        threads = config['threads']
    conda:
        "../envs/environment_fastp.yml"
    shell:
        """
        python workflow/scripts/run_fastp.py --threads {params.threads} --directory_path {wildcard.path} --sra_accession {wildcards.sra}
        """

rule ribodetector_se:
    input:
        fastq = get_ribodetector
    output:
        fastq = "{path}/{sra}/{sra}_ribodetector.fastq"
    params:
        threads = config['threads']
    conda:
        "../envs/environment_ribodetector.yml"
    shell:
        """
        python workflow/scripts/run_ribodetector.py --threads {params.threads} --directory_path {wildcards.path} --sra_accession {wildcards.sra}
        """ 

rule ribodetector_pe:
    input:
        fastq = get_ribodetector
    output:
        fastq1 = "{path}/{sra}/{sra}_ribodetector1.fastq",
        fastq2 = "{path}/{sra}/{sra}_ribodetector2.fastq"
    params:
        threads = config['threads']
    conda:
        "../envs/environment_ribodetector.yml"
    shell:
        """
        python workflow/scripts/run_ribodetector.py --threads {params.threads} --directory_path {wildcards.path} --sra_accession {wildcards.sra}
        """
```

mapping.smk:

```
rule mapping_se:
    input:
        fastq = get_ribodetector
    output:
        fastq = temp(local("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_SRA_unaligned.fastq")),
        sam = temp(local("{path}/{sra}/{sra}.sam"))
    params:
        threads = config['threads'],
        host_code_for_mapping = config['host_code_for_mapping'],
        email = config['email'],
        host_genome_path = config['host_genome_path'],
        use_host_genome_path = config['use_host_genome_path']
    conda:
        "../envs/environment_mapping.yml"
    shell:
        """
        python workflow/scripts/run_mapping.py --threads {params.threads} --directory_path {wildcards.path} --sra_accession {wildcards.sra} --host_code_for_mapping {params.host_code_for_mapping} --email {params.email} --host_genome_path {params.host_genome_path} --use_host_genome_path {params.use_host_genome_path}
        """ 

rule mapping_pe:
    input:
        fastq = get_ribodetector
    output:
        fastq1 = temp(local("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_SRA_unaligned_1.fastq")),
        fastq2 = temp(local("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_SRA_unaligned_2.fastq")),
        sam = temp(local("{path}/{sra}/{sra}.sam"))
    params:
        threads = config['threads'],
        host_code_for_mapping = config['host_code_for_mapping'],
        email = config['email'],
        host_genome_path = config['host_genome_path'],
        use_host_genome_path = config['use_host_genome_path']
    conda:
        "../envs/environment_mapping.yml"
    shell:
        """
        python workflow/scripts/run_mapping.py --threads {params.threads} --directory_path {wildcards.path} --sra_accession {wildcards.sra} --host_code_for_mapping {params.host_code_for_mapping} --email {params.email} --host_genome_path {params.host_genome_path} --use_host_genome_path {params.use_host_genome_path}
        """
```

assembly.smk:

```
ruleorder: spades_pe > spades_se

rule spades_se:
    input:
        fastq = get_mapping
    output:
        spades_assembly = "{path}/{sra}/{sra}_spades_transcripts.fasta"
    params:
        threads = config['threads'],
        ram = config['ram']
    conda:
        "../envs/environment_spades.yml"
    shell:
        """
        python workflow/scripts/run_spades.py --threads {params.threads} --directory_path {wildcards.path} --sra_accession {wildcards.sra} --ram {params.ram}
        """ 
    
rule spades_pe:
    input:
        fastq = get_mapping
    output:
        spades_assembly = "{path}/{sra}/{sra}_spades_transcripts.fasta"
    params:
        threads = config['threads'],
        ram = config['ram']
    conda:
        "../envs/environment_spades.yml"
    shell:
        """
        python workflow/scripts/run_spades.py --threads {params.threads} --directory_path {wildcards.path} --sra_accession {wildcards.sra} --ram {params.ram}
        """
```

And for some reason, the rule of sra_toolkit.smk is not running even though I specified the output in the rule all:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
candidate job all
    wildcards: 
candidate job download_and_extract_fastq
    wildcards: path=/home/apis/Icaro3, sra=SRR1525658
selected job download_and_extract_fastq
    wildcards: path=/home/apis/Icaro3, sra=SRR1525658
file /home/apis/Icaro3/SRR1525658/check_SRR1525658.txt:
    Producer found, hence exceptions are ignored.

candidate job download_and_extract_fastq
    wildcards: path=/home/apis/Icaro3, sra=SRR1525659
selected job download_and_extract_fastq
    wildcards: path=/home/apis/Icaro3, sra=SRR1525659
file /home/apis/Icaro3/SRR1525659/check_SRR1525659.txt:
    Producer found, hence exceptions are ignored.

candidate job download_and_extract_fastq
    wildcards: path=/home/apis/Icaro3, sra=SRR1525660
selected job download_and_extract_fastq
    wildcards: path=/home/apis/Icaro3, sra=SRR1525660
file /home/apis/Icaro3/SRR1525660/check_SRR1525660.txt:
    Producer found, hence exceptions are ignored.

The command used was: conda run -n common fastq-dump.3.0.8 -X 1 -Z --split-spot SRR1525658
The command used was: conda run -n common fastq-dump.3.0.8 -X 1 -Z --split-spot SRR1525658
candidate job spades_pe
    wildcards: path=/home/apis/Icaro3, sra=SRR1525658
The command used was: conda run -n common fastq-dump.3.0.8 -X 1 -Z --split-spot SRR1525658
candidate job ribodetector_se
    wildcards: path=/home/apis/Icaro3, sra=SRR1525658
The command used was: conda run -n common fastq-dump.3.0.8 -X 1 -Z --split-spot SRR1525658
candidate job fastp_se
    wildcards: path=/home/apis/Icaro3, sra=SRR1525658
candidate job spades_se
    wildcards: path=/home/apis/Icaro3, sra=SRR1525658
candidate job ribodetector_se
    wildcards: path=/home/apis/Icaro3, sra=SRR1525658
candidate job fastp_se
    wildcards: path=/home/apis/Icaro3, sra=SRR1525658
WorkflowError:
MissingInputException: Missing input files for rule fastp_se:
    output: /home/apis/Icaro3/SRR1525658/SRR1525658_filtered.fastq, /home/apis/Icaro3/SRR1525658/fastp.json, /home/apis/Icaro3/SRR1525658/fastp.html, /home/apis/Icaro3/SRR1525658/adapter_sequences.fasta
    wildcards: path=/home/apis/Icaro3, sra=SRR1525658
    affected files:
        /home/apis/Icaro3/SRR1525658/SRR1525658.fastq
MissingInputException: Missing input files for rule fastp_se:
    output: /home/apis/Icaro3/SRR1525658/SRR1525658_filtered.fastq, /home/apis/Icaro3/SRR1525658/fastp.json, /home/apis/Icaro3/SRR1525658/fastp.html, /home/apis/Icaro3/SRR1525658/adapter_sequences.fasta
    wildcards: path=/home/apis/Icaro3, sra=SRR1525658
    affected files:
        /home/apis/Icaro3/SRR1525658/SRR1525658.fastq
```

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I think the problem might be that in the rule all you call the functions get_fastq and get_fastp where the argument is wildcards. You should not call those functions there but define the desired inputs as in SRA_ARCHIVE

Comment: those functions should be used only by the other rules, not all

Comment: But I thought that in the rule "all" I'd add all the expected files. The inputs coming from get_fastq and get_fastp are expected files in the pipeline, but if they are paired or single-end, this is going to be defined during the run.

Comment: And "wildcards.sra" still not working in common.smk. Here's the error: InputFunctionException in rule ribodetector_pe in file /home/apis/final_BeeNA_server/workflow/rules/trimming.smk, line 35:
Error:
  AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'sra'
Wildcards:

Traceback:
  File "/home/apis/final_BeeNA_server/workflow/rules/common.smk", line 33, in get_fastp

Comment: you need to specify the expected files in rule all like you do for SRA_ARCHIVE. You get the error because your wildcards have not have been created yet, and you are calling them in the two functions.

Comment: instead of calling the two functions in rule all add: ```expand("{path}/{sra}/{sra}_1_filtered.fastq", sra=config['SRA_acessions'], path = config['directory_path'])```

Comment: I'll do this! Thank you very much!

Comment: let me know if it works so that I can reply with an answer

Comment: I did what you recommended, but now the rule from sra_toolkit.smk is not running anymore. It starts directly from trimming.smk. Why this? I added the changes to the original question after EDIT